# Golang goroutine endless loop memory leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I have encountered strange (as for a man who is new to golang) behaviour of my goroutine:

```
go func(...) {
  for {
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
     ...
  } 
}
```

It slowly eats RAM. I understand that it is caused by calling `make` in an endless loop; it just allocates new memory every time. But i don't quite get why this construction:

```
  var buffer []byte
  for {
    buffer = make([]byte, 1024)
     ...
    }
  }
```

..works well, while the first one doesn't. Shouldn't garbage collector detect that memory which old `buf` was pointing at is unreachable in both cases? And maybe there are some other similar traps that a go-newbie should know?

Also, if i will return this goroutine, will leaked memory be freed?

**UPD**: full memory leaking routine code:

```
go func(dataChannel chan []byte, errorChannel chan error) {
  for {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err := conn.Read(buf) 
    if err != nil {
      errorChannel<- err
      break
    }
    dataChannel<- buf
  } 
} (dataChannel, errorChannel)
```

Comment: Never use a busy loop, it's always a mistake. The first just happens to break things worse than the second, because the first _could_ be doing something else. Yes, the memory can eventually be freed if you get that far.

Comment: Сould you please be more specific on dangers that such busy loop can possibly hide? This routine reads from socket and sends recieved data through channel. AFAIK, net.Read() blocks the execution and consumes no excess CPU time, and there is a loop break in case that TCP connection will broke. I can make it one-timed, and re-run it after getting message, but i don't see yet how it could be dangerous.

Comment: "And maybe there are some other similar traps that a go-newbie should know?" These are not traps, neither to newbies nor to veterans. These are  handcrafted pathological code snippets nobody would ever write.

Comment: @navij: Then your example isn't complete enough. If you are doing something besides calling make in the loop then your problem is likely elsewhere. Please show a complete example. If you want to see how memory is being collected, set `GODEBUG=gctrace=1`

Comment: @JimB: I have added the full code, but i've cut everything else because it's quite simple and i did some tests which have showed that declaring `buf` outside of the loop solved the problem. I was just curious about what is causing such behaviour.

Comment: @navij: that's not causing a leak, and is perfectly fine (though you're discarding the number of bytes read, so you don't know how much of each buf is actually valid). You're keeping the memory around in some other way if it continues to grow.

Comment: @Volker I have no doubts that you are absolutely right about my code. The sole reason i have asked this question was to write better.

Comment: @JimB That's strange. I've run a clean test: endless loop within main(), 4 looped routines that are making a new `buf` each run and outputs first bit of it, nothing else, and got memory usage skyrocketing. And after declaring `buf` before the loop the problem disappeared completely. I checked it more than once, and always got a growing memory usage. Here are my test sources, if you are interested: [leaking](https://pastebin.com/aFXwXvQT) and [non-leaking](https://pastebin.com/gR0ks0Xs)

Comment: @navij: that first example is exactly what we're talking about, it's a useless loop that is spinning as fast as possible, it breaks your program, but no sane program should ever have that. That is not equivalent to a loop like in your question that calls Read on a net.Conn.

Comment: @JimB Yes, of course i don't do that in my code, it's for testing sake's only. But the leak is there nonetheless, and it works absolutely the same as in my program. These two test code samples are absolutely idnetical except for buffer declaration, and one have leak, and the second doesn't. I don't understand how declaring variable before loop and then reassigning it inside differs from declaring it each time. Maybe garbage collector ignores loop variable scope until it ends?

Answer (score 0):

```
  for {
        var mem runtime.MemStats
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&mem)
        fmt.Printf("alloc [%v] \t heapAlloc [%v] \n", mem.Alloc, mem.HeapAlloc)
        time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    }
```

- added the above lines in your main function for loop (in the leaking code link given above)
- new code : https://pastebin.com/UQbYuVN7
- while running this shows that memory is being re-collected at regular intervals by gc

Comment: That is really confusing, because here are my outputs of your code:

alloc [78696]    heapAlloc [78696]
alloc [80904]    heapAlloc [80904]
alloc [82328]    heapAlloc [82328]

and, after 10-20 seconds:

alloc [128504]       heapAlloc [128504]

I was running it on Win7 and CentOS. I am really confused right now.

Comment: And, once again, after putting `buf` declaration before loop, i got perfectly normal mem usage, swinging around 3-4 MBs. And it doesn't seem to be platform-specific or golang version-specific bug, since i encounter it on different systems.

Comment: I should add that on Windows i have go 1.8, and on CentOS 1.6.3

Comment: Or one could just use `GODEBUG=gctrace=1` and see all the details from garbage collection and the memory scavenger.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, you were absolutely right about that. I got no output from gctrace, so i started digging, and i used ReadGCStats, which showed me, that GC didn't run even once. Setting GOGC to default value (100) seems to be the answer. In my excuse i can say that i haven't encountered any info leading to the fact that GOGC variable should be set up by hands after GO installation, so i thought that GC is enabled by default.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks to **JimB** and his advice to set enviroment var `GODEBUG=gctrace=1`, i discovered that i had no env var GOGC set in my system, because of which garbage collector wasn't functioning at all. Setting it to [default value](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) was everything that i needed.

Comment: Something else is going on in your setup. You don't need to set GOGC to turn on the GC.

Comment: Well, i have no idea on what it could be - both Win7 and CentOS have fresh installations of GO, they both have different versions, and i haven't done anything but writing some simple code in educational purposes. I have some modules from github imported, but they all seems to be trusted ones, like go-sql-driver/mysql.